# Angular form validation not getting fired for author field

Tags: angular, forms, validation

angular form validation if condition is not getting binded for author field.

angular 7

**HTML:**

```
<div class="form-group"> 
  <label class="col-md-4">Author Name </label>
  <input type="text"  class="form-control" formControlName="author" #author /></div>
<div *ngIf="author.invalid && (author.dirty || author.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
  <div *ngIf="author.errors.required">
     Author is required.
  </div>
</div>
```

**TS:**

```
import { FormControl, FormGroup,  FormBuilder,  Validators } from '@angular/forms';
bookForm = new FormGroup({author: new FormControl('', Validators.required)});

get author() {
  return this.bookForm.get('author');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `#author` from the input HTML element because its [`Template Variables`](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-reference-variables--var-) which don't have any property like `invalid`, `touched` etc.

Template Variables:

> A template reference variable is often a reference to a DOM element within a template. It can also be a reference to an Angular component or directive or a web component.
>
> Use the hash symbol (#) to declare a reference variable. The #phone declares a phone variable on an  element.

[`Updated_Stackblitz`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3e3fyf)

Answer (score 0):

Try this condition

```
 bookForm.get('author').touched && bookForm.get('author').invalid && 
 bookForm.get('author').errors.required
```

Answer (score 0):

If `FormControl` is valid, `errors` field returns `undefined`. Therefore, you can use only `*ngIf="author.errors"`. if you want to show the error when it is dirty and invalid, you can use this:

```
<div *ngIf="author.dirty && author.errors" class="alert alert-danger">
  <ng-container *ngIf="author.errors.required">
     Author is required.
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     <form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form)" 
            [ngClass]="{'was-validated': form.invalid && (form.dirty || form.touched)}">
            <div class="" ngModelGroup="User">
                <h2 class="text-center">Registration page</h2>
                <br />                 
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" name="firstname" required
                        ngModel #firstname="ngModel">
                    <span class="help-bpx" *ngIf="firstname.touched && !firstname.valid ">Please enter the
                        firstname</span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" name="lastname" required ngModel
                        #lastname="ngModel">
                    <span class="help-bpx" *ngIf="lastname.touched && !lastname.valid ">Please enter the
                        lastname</span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" email
                        required ngModel #email="ngModel">
                    <span class="help-bpx" *ngIf="email.touched && !email.valid ">Please enter the Email
                        Value</span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="custom-file">
                        <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="customFile" required ngModel name="file" #file="ngModel">
                        <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">Choose file</label>
                      </div>
                </div>
                
                <br />
                <div class="align-center">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!form.valid">Register</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```